# PL/SQL - Compare sets of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Sample Data:

```
ID       VALUE
1001     A
1001     B
1002     A
1002     A
1003     A
1003     B
```

Standard of comparison IS ID=1001

From here, I want to look at all other IDs != 1001... I need to make sure:

1. Every other SET of records grouped by ID has the same quantity of
   associated rows.  In this example, every one passes this test.
2. For every value associated with ID=1001, an EXACT match must be found for
   all other IDs.  In this example, 1002 will fail because although it
   has the correct number of rows, it has two 'A' values, and no 'B'
   value.

Logically - this seems simple enough... but I have been beating my head against the keyboard for some time now.

Any wisdom or Band-Aids would be appreciated.

Regards,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do the first query:

```
select s.id
from sample s
where s.id <> 101
group by s.id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from sample s where id = 101);
```

The second is similar.  The following comes close:

```
select s.id
from sample s full outer join
     (select s.*
      from sample s
      where s.id = 101
     ) s100
     on s.value = s100.vaue
where s.id <> 101
group by s.id
having count(*) = count(s.value) and count(s.value) = count(s100.value);
```

The problem with this query is the presence of duplicates.  To fix that, we need to enumerate the value for each id:

```
select s.id
from (select s.*,  row_number() over (partition by s.id, s.value order by s.id) as seqnum
      from sample s
     ) s full outer join
     (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by s.id, s.value order by s.id) as seqnum
      from sample s
      where s.id = 101
     ) s100
     on s.value = s100.vaue and s.seqnum = s100.seqnum
where s.id <> 101
group by s.id
having count(*) = count(s.value) and count(s.value) = count(s100.value);
```

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar . . . There was probably a lot of cut-and-paste, but, the most useful course that I took in high school was touch typing.

Comment: Gordon - thanks for chiming in.  I appreciate the careful thought.  Mostly this worked, but it failed to notice when one set had few rows, but commensurate data anyway.  I ended up doing something with listagg to flatten the rows into a CSV list.  Gross... but effective.

Comment: @MichaelConroy . . . The last version should work in that case.  It checks for matches both on the value and on the number of values.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without PL/SQL

```
with base_values as (
   select id, value
   from the_table 
   where id = 1001
), other_values as (
   select id, value
   from the_table 
   where id <> 1001
)
select ov.id
from base_values bv
  join other_values ov on bv.value = ov.value
group by ov.id
having count(distinct ov.value) = (select count(distinct value) from base_values)
```

Comment: Horse Doe - thanks for helping.  As with Gordon's solution, this got me most of the way there.  Not every use case was covered, but you both pointed me in the right direction.  For the record, I used a few WITH clauses to get me close, and then an INNER JOIN after aggregating.  Ugly - but it worked.  And since it's a one-off query to screen out some discrepant data that MAY be in there from production, I'm not worried about pretty.